# Difference between principal directions and principal component scores in the context of dimensionality reduction

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have performed principal component analysis (PCA) of data matrix $X$ by doing singular value decomposition (SVD)
$$
X = U S V',
$$
where the columns of $V$ are the principal directions/axes and the columns of $US$ are the principal components (scores).

I have 12 attributes so I also get 12 principal directions/axes. I have found the variance explained and chose to consider only 6 of the 12 principal directions since these 6 explain enough of variance.

But I get a little confused:

1. Most websites about PCA say that I should choose some principal components, but isn't it more correct to choose principal directions/axes since my objective is to reduce dimensionality?
2. I have seen that my matrix $V$ consists of 12 column vectors, each with 12 elements. If I choose 6 of these columns vectors, each vector still has 12 elements - but how is this possible if I have reduced the dimensionality?
3. Besides, there are 12 column vectors of $US$, representing the principal components (scores), but each column vector has an awful lot of elements. What does it mean?

I am really confused. I have read a lot about this, but I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: Principal axis/direction/dimension/component are one thing. It is a derived variable. As an axis, it is "rotated" in space relative the original axes-variables. `V` is the matrix of the angles (the cosines) between the original variables (rows of `V`) and the PCs (columns of `V`). The data points are then projected onto the PC axes, yielding coordinates `US` on them called the PC values or scores. Note that `US=XV'` which makes it clearer that the rows of data `X` (data points) were projected onto axes `V` which were in turn the result of rotation of the columns of `X` (original variables).

Comment: But why does the column vectors have so many elements/dimensions? It doesn't mmake sense if I have reduced the dimensionality to only 6 by choosing only 6 column vectors

Comment: and how can `US=XV'` if `X=USV'`? Shouldn't it be `X=USV' <=> `US=X(V')^(-1)`?

Comment: Columns of $US$ have as many elements as columns of $X$. If you had 1000 points in 12 dimensions, then dimensionality reduction from 12 to 6 means that you select 6 principal axes (columns of $V$) and project your data onto them, obtaining 6 columns of $US$, each having 1000 values -- one value for each data point. In the end you have 1000 points in 6 dimensions. Regarding the math, $US=XV$ because $XV=USV^\top V = US$. Matrix $V$ is orthogonal, so $V^{-1}=V^\top$. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these things are covered in my answers in the following two threads:

1. [Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282)
2. [What exactly is called "principal component" in PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88118)

Still, here I will try to answer your specific concerns.

---

Think about it like that. You have, let's say, $1000$ data points in $12$-dimensional space (i.e. your data matrix $X$ is of $1000\times12$ size). PCA finds directions in this space that capture maximal variance. So for example PC1 direction is a certain axis in this $12$-dimensional space, i.e. a vector of length $12$. PC2 direction is another axis, etc. These directions are given by columns of your matrix $V$. All your $1000$ data points can be projected onto each of these directions/axes, yielding coordinates of $1000$ data points along each PC direction; these projections are what is called PC scores, and what I prefer to simply call PCs. They are given by the columns of $US$.

**So for each PC you have a $12$-dimensional vector specifying the *PC direction* or axis and a $1000$-dimensional vector specifying the *PC projection* on this axis.**

"Reducing dimensionality" means that you take several PC projections as your new variables (e.g. if you take $6$ of them, then your new data matrix will be of $1000\times 6$ size) and essentially forget about the PC directions in the original $12$-dimensional space.

---

> Most websites about PCA say that I should choose some principal components, but isn't it more correct to choose principal directions/axes since my objective is to reduce dimensionality?

This is equivalent. One column of $V$ corresponds to one column of $US$. You can say that you choose some columns of $V$ or you can say that you choose some columns of $US$. Doesn't matter. Also, by "principal components" some people mean columns of $V$ and some people mean columns of $US$. Again, most of the time it does not matter.

> I have seen that my matrix V consists of 12 column vectors, each with 12 elements. If I choose 6 of these columns vectors, each vector still has 12 elements - but how is this possible if I have reduced the dimensionality?

You chose 6 axes in the 12-dimensional space. If you only consider these 6 axes and discard the other 6, then you reduced your dimensionality from 12 to 6. But each of the 6 chosen axes is originally a vector in the 12-dimensional space. No contradiction.

> Besides, there are 12 column vectors of US, representing the principal components (scores), but each column vector has an awful lot of elements. What does it mean?

As I said, these are the projections on the principal axes. If your data matrix had 1000 points, then each PC score vector will have 1000 points. Makes sense.